# How to compare OpenCL with native code performance properly?

Tags: performance, opencl, gpu, benchmarking

Intel provides some advices on comparing OpenCL with native code [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdk-for-opencl-applications-performance-debugging-intro).

Are there any additional recommendations? I am particularly interested whether OpenCL is usually compared with straightforward C/C++ code or if optimizazions of the sequential code are also taken into account. What is the case with intrinsic functions?

Comment: I don't know what kind of general answer you're expecting here. Surely this depends very, very heavily on the application.

Comment: For example, is your application latency sensitive, or mostly throughput? How do your data sets scale? The scaling behaviour on CPU and GPU will often be very different. What's your target hardware? Moreover, there are multiple reasons for offloading to a GPU - it could be that you want to free up the CPU for something else, or that the GPU is actually faster than the CPU on the specific computation, or that it's more energy efficient. "Performance" can mean a lot of things, and the proper way to measure it will depend on your application. With that in mind, can you be more specific?

Comment: Looking at this a different way: assuming someone can answer your question, what will you use this information for? What decision are you trying to make? The question might make more sense given that context.

Comment: The question is really too general. In my case, the GPU is significantly faster than the CPU on the specific computation. The information I asked for is either for presentation purposes - if I want to present the performance enhancement to the audience, comparing with straightforward CPU code without optimizations would show more improvement than when comparing with optimized code. However, I was wondering  what is the "usual" way to do this, since in most publications on the topic there is no information about the sequential code.

Comment: If you compare to single threaded code that hasn't been vectorised, emphasise this.

Comment: OpenMP can easily give you a multi-threaded program - could be a day's work and you've got something to show. That's also worthwhile to show because someone else looking at your work might not have access to a GPU (e.g. running code on a CPU-only supercomputer). Note also that OpenMP has a SIMD directive that may vectorise some for loops, although it's harder to get right - if you give it a quick try and see a speed up, report it too. I find those comparisons more useful and, most importantly, explain what directives and changes to the code were made at each step.

Comment: From a funding perspective, if your results show parallel CPU performance, it becomes possible for readers to evaluate whether purchasing a GPU is worthwhile assuming they are using your code or trying to develop similar code. If the GPU is say 2~4x faster than parallel CPU code but the running time is still acceptable to the reader, they may choose not to invest in a GPU or developing for a GPU. Alternatively, if the speed difference makes a sufficient cost difference for the reader, they could use that in a motivation for funding for buying the GPU.